# Do I need to use molly/toggle bolts to mount an over the range microwave if I can attach the mounting bracket to studs?

Tags: appliances, microwave-oven

I recently bought a used KitchenAid microwave (model khmc1857wss0) and have been watching videos on how to mount it. Some videos have them using toggle bolts to mount it, others just screw it into the studs and potentially use drywall anchors for a few extra support holes. Given the weight of the microwave, would it be safe to not use toggle bolts so long as I can drill the mounting bracket into studs?

I'm asking because I need to order most of the mounting hardware (since it wasn't included when I bought it) and am trying to determine what parts I need to get.

Answer (score 4):

You are better off mounting it to the studs. If there's no studs near the edge then I would add a toggle there.

Answer (score 0):

Molly and toggle style bolts are for use when you can't hit the stud for whatever reason.  They are designed to expand behind the drywall and take up enough surface space to be able to carry the load - but drywall is overall a fairly weak material, and using it as a load bearer is never the preference.

Since you can find the stud, use that - the wood is MUCH stronger, can endure a lot more pressure from different directions, and a good sized well fitting screw in wood will withstand tons more force than a drywall mount.